# Svg horizontal line does not appear in chrome with particular zoom level

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, svg, horizontal-line

I have created a bar graph using svg. There are few horiztonal rulers which are basically svg line with black stroke.
Issue is as below

- The horizontal rulers disappear when zoom is 75% or 25%.
- The horizontal rulers dont disappear in other browsers
- The horizontal rulers dont disappear when they are rotated and made
  vertical.

Observations:

1. If initial zoom is 75% and then you zoom out or zoom in then the
   lines appear
2. But when the zoom again is equal or 75% or 25% then the lines
   disappear

[Jsbin Link](http://jsbin.com/vazuxu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Images for reference:
[image]

and the one with issue:
[image]

Comment: Are you using some library or is it your custom code? In any case a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem would allow much more relevant answers

Comment: custom svg code in ember-cli

Comment: @KirillSlatin i ve added jsbin link

Answer (score 1):

What's the reason to apply external schema? If you replace horizontal line declaration with the following code it survives zoom out

```
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" class="black-line"></line>   
      <line x1="0" y1="20%" x2="100%" y2="20%" class="black-line"></line>   
      <line x1="0" y1="40%" x2="100%" y2="40%" class="black-line"></line>   
      <line x1="0" y1="60%" x2="100%" y2="60%" class="black-line"></line>   
      <line x1="0" y1="80%" x2="100%" y2="80%" class="black-line"></line>   
      <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="100%" class="black-line"></line>
```

Comment: yeah i thought that would work but i didn try : ) Your answer definitely solves my problem but does not answer why it doesn show in chrome! So upvote for that : )
Thanks tho  :)

Comment: i think every browser has troubles when rendering that xlink. For example IE 11 renders differnet width dependant on size on container (not zoom) and also hies these lines when zoom is 35%

Comment: Not true! If i use rect instead of line then it renders just fine. The issue is just with line. http://jsbin.com/vazuxu/6/edit

Comment: I am not saying about all xlink templates. I am talking about `hor-line`

Comment: Btw, i've tried the xlink `rect` and doesn't behave much better. On 90% and 50% it doesn't have the top border in Chrome

Comment: hmmm top-border! again related to horizontal line!

Comment: Btw not true in my case, both 90% and 50% appear fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79306/discussion-between-kirill-slatin-and-wishy).